# Reading and writing to csv file and remove commas

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write out to a csv but I only get the last line written to the csv,
I presume that it is overwriting the previous line because it is in the loop statement but I cannot figure out how to get this to work?
the csv that is generated has successfully removed any commas within the line
Any help appreciated as I'm new to this,
Thanks

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    TextFieldParser tfp = new TextFieldParser("C:\\imports\\test1.csv");

    tfp.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
    tfp.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
    while (!tfp.EndOfData) {

        string[] fields = tfp.ReadFields();

        // remove the commas and double-quotes from the fields.
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
            fields[i] = fields[i].Replace(",", " ").Replace("\"", "");

        // this is the output
        using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\imports\\testing.csv"))
            writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", fields) + "\n");
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Complete");
    tfp.Close();
}
```

Comment: Move the using statement out of the while loop

Comment: You should create the StreamWriter outside of the `while` loop

Comment: but when i move the output statements outside of the while loop i get "The name 'fields' does not exist in the current context", can you show what the code should look like?

Comment: May I ask why you are bent upon corrupting your data? Embedded `,` characters should be escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, it keeps overwriting the file everytime you write a new line. This is caused by opening a new `StreamWriter` everytime, instead you should open the `StreamWriter` once, and keep using that same instance, for example like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    TextFieldParser tfp = new TextFieldParser("C:\\imports\\test1.csv");

    tfp.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
    tfp.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
    using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\imports\\testing.csv")) {
        while (!tfp.EndOfData) {

            string[] fields = tfp.ReadFields();

            // remove the commas and double-quotes from the fields.
            for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
                fields[i] = fields[i].Replace(",", " ").Replace("\"", "");

            // this is the output
            writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", fields) + "\n");
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Complete");
    tfp.Close();
}
```

As you can see I only moved the `using` statement with the `StreamWriter` before the `while` loop (and added some curly braces to clearly indicate the scope of the `using` statement). This way only one `StreamWriter` is created, and you can keep using it within the loop to write all lines.

Comment: Thank you, working perfect now, I can see where i was going wrong